# How to get details of items in drop down menu using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and in that database i have a table called `courses_details`. I want this when user select one course from a drop down menu, information of that course i.e (CourseCode, CourseTitle, CourseCredits) can be displayed in a form using php. I m unable to get it. I will be honored if anyone can help me out.

```
<form action="courses.php" method="POST" class="FormStyle">
    <select name="courses">
    <option value="ITC">Intro. To Computing</option>
    <option value="OOP">Object Oriented Programming</option>
    <option value="DS">Data Structures</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Search and use ajax

Comment: have you problems with the PHP/MySQL query or you don't know how to get the result of the selected item ?

Comment: @OldPadawan i don't know how to get result of the selected item.

Comment: in courses.php you'll get the posted value of  'courses' -> `$selectedcourse = $_POST['courses'];` you need to add a submit button or an JS action `on change` to the select

Answer (score 0):

So this is the form that creates the $_POST[submit] and $_POST['courses'] variables.`members` will be the page you wish to display the form with the info from your query.

```
<form action="members.php" method="POST" class="FormStyle">
    <select name="courses">
      <option value="ITC">Intro. To Computing</option>
      <option value="OOP">Object Oriented Programming</option>
      <option value="DS">Data Structures</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**The $_POST variable as defined in the PHP Manual** => `An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.`.

**Remember,** `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` is the input 'button' that is used to submit the form once the user presses the button. The name in this input is defined as `name="submit"`. So once we read the manual on POST variables, we see that it is an assoc array of variables from our form that is passing through the http request. So we construct our logic to check if the button `submit` was pressed. `if($_POST['submit'])`, run code associated with a successful button press. Within the input fields the `name` attribute is filled with a ternary operators results. One can add `selected` and/or `checked` using the same method, or any number of attributes for that matter.

Here you would construct your logic to query the DB and table holding the value. Once you have a successful query, define the variables you wish to print/echo.

**UPDATED**: Your courses.php page would look something like.

```
"your_external_page_source".php

define("HOST", 'yourhostvalue');
define("USER", 'yourusername');
define("PASSWORD", 'yourpassword');
define("DATABASE", 'yourdbname');
define("DB_MEMBERS", 'yourdbtable');
```

Then on "form_page".php

```
include = 'constants.php';
if($_POST['submit']){//here we check to see if the input 'submit' was posted through the form

  //success define your variable(s)

  //$courses will now hold the $_POST variable that passed through the http POST method (the form names as defined in your various forms tags)
  $courses = $_POST['courses'];//assign the value of your select field to the variable $courses

  //connect to DB if not already
  $db = new mysqli(HOST, USER ,PASSWORD, DATABASE);//CONSTANTS from a linked file

// Check for errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
//using an example DB with a table defined as a constant DB_MEMBERS
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `DB_MEMBERS` WHERE `courses`=".$courses);
if($result->num_rows){// if rows are present from the query
     // Cycle through results and define your variables
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $courseCode = htmlspecialchars($row['CourseCode']); //*avoid possible exploits with htmlspecialchars()
        $courseTitle = htmlspecialchars($row['CourseTitle']); //*
        $courseCredits = htmlspecialchars($row['CourseCredits']);//*
    }
}
```

Create a form to display your results.

```
<form action="somelink.php" method="POST">
   <input class="form-group-item" value="<?php $cCode = ($courseCode > 0 ? echo $courseCode : echo ''); echo  $cCode; ?>" name="courseCode">
   <input class="form-group-item" value="<?php $cTitle = ($courseTitle > 0 ? echo $courseTitle  : echo ''); echo  $cTitle; ?>" name="courseTitle">
   <input class="form-group-item" value="<?php $cCredits  = ($courseCredits > 0 ? echo $courseCredits : echo ''); echo  $cCredits;  ?>" name="cCredits ">
   <input type="submit" name="submitMembers" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[Check out the official PHP $_POST Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) there is also `$_GET`->sent via the URL `site.com?get=".$somevalue;` and `$_REQUEST->(Both $_POST and $_GET)`

***Code has NOT been checked***

Comment: Does $_POST('submit') and $_POST('courses') work?  Shouldn't that be $_POST['submit'] and $_POST['courses'] - brackets not parentheses?

Comment: @Jason See my updated answer, you are 100% correct. Best